# Specifying a relation through multiple shared foreign keys

Tags: python, django, has-many-through

Let's say we have 4 models, lets call them `Alpha`, `Beta`, `Gamma`, and `Delta` and the first two are something like:

```py
class Alpha(models.Model):
    gamma = models.ForeignKey(Gamma, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    delta = models.ForeignKey(Delta, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['gamma_id', 'delta_id'])
        ]


class Beta(models.Model):
    gamma = models.ForeignKey(Gamma, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    delta = models.ForeignKey(Delta, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

As you can see the two foreign keys can be used to associate any number of rows from Beta with one row from Alpha. There is essentially a one to many relationship between Beta and Alpha.

For various reasons it is not feasible to replace the two foreign keys in Beta with a foreign key to Alpha.

Is there a way to define a relationship on Alpha that returns all the rows from Beta that have the same `gamma_id` and `delta_id`

Answer (score 0):

For an `Alpha` model named `some_alpha` you can retrieve the `Beta` items with:

```
Beta.objects.filter(gamma__alpha=some_alpha, delta__alpha=some_alpha)
```

We thus will check that the relations that span over `gamma` and `delta` refer to the same `alpha` object.

Comment: Yes but can I define a formal relation, so `alpha__beta` will work.

Comment: @kaan_a: Django can query in reverse or over many-to-many relations. It uses the `related_query_name`, which is the model name by default. `alpha__beta` will not work, since a `Beta` object has no `alpha` relation, not forward nor "backward".